# Ski trails/piste map data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, sports, ski

Is it possible to download ski trail/piste data for major European and other resorts? I'm looking for polyline data showing the major runs in a resort - the kind of data you'd see on a piste map.

Openstreetmap seems to have quite extensive chairlift data, but not the actual runs down.

Comment: this is probably best asked on OpenData

Comment: you can see OSM coverage from the Piste Project --> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Piste_Maps

Answer (score 2):

Switzerland's [geo.admin.ch portal has some ski routes](https://s.geo.admin.ch/7a2ddc746b)

[image]

[image]

> The digital ski routes are based on the Snowshoe and Ski Tour Maps 1:50,000 and the National Map 1:50,000. They contain specific information for snow sports in the alpine and pre-alpine area of ​​Switzerland. Special conditions for snowshoe and ski route data: The ski and snowshoe routes are to be regarded as general indications of direction.
>
> ...
>
> For further information see: www.sac-cas.ch/guidebook

I just can't figure out how to download. Maybe you can reach out to them on [twitter](https://twitter.com/swiss_geoportal).

Comment: The metadata page says to contact geodata@swisstopo.ch, Federal Office of Topography, Wabern, 3084, CH.